# Linux dual-boot on self-encrypted drive (Dell Data Protection)

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, encryption, opal

At work I have a recent Dell Latitude E6440 laptop. The IT department allowed me to install Linux on it on a dedicated partitions they created. However, they won't support me if anything gets broken because of the Linux installation. So far so good :-)

This laptop has a self-encrypted drive (SED also known as [Full-Encrypted Drive or FED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption)). The hard drive (form Seagate) uses the TCG OPAL SATA standard and Dell has its own layer on top which is called [Dell Data Protection](http://www.Dell.com/DataProtection). Again so far so good.

My concern is that this new implementation of their Data Protection suite looks **quite integrated with Microsoft Windows and Active Directory**. On older version of this suite, I was using a dedicated login and password which were different than the Windows one. But on this latest version, I need to use my Active Directory credentials and I do not need to authenticate on Windows, the successfull authentication is somehow passed to Windows during the boot process.

Now I have already tried to boot on a live USB and it worked successfully provided that I first wait for Windows to boot then do a soft reboot and then I was able to boot from the USB disk and into the live USB. So this is possible to have Linux on a second drive.

**Question**

However, with such set-up is it possible to have Linux on a dedicated partition (same HDD as Windows) which would then installed its own bootloader (e.g. Grub2) without breaking this special boot process?

Note: I do not mind if I need to login once at boot to "unlock" the drive and once again to login in the OS. That's what I have been used to anyway.

Extra info: I plan to have Ubuntu LTS as a dual boot on this machine. I already have Windows 7 Pro/Entreprise installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

We have a super suportive IT department and they made me a full disk backup after which I went on installing Ubuntu. And the installation is a success. Dual-booting in both Windows 7 or Ubuntu.

First I started the laptop as usual and booted under Windows. I then plugged in the USB stick with the Ubuntu installation image (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) and rebooted the machine.

While in the reboot process I pressed F12 (or F10 can't remember) to "pop up" the boot menu to choose the boot device. I choose "UEFI USB Flash Drive" (or equivalent name). Ubuntu started up and I choose to install it. I partitionned manually the available space and it a standard installation.

After installation, the system rebooted but I got directly into Windows, no Grub promt. I perhaps miss configured the boot loader during manual partitionning (surprisingly as I had explectictly chosen sda, but anyway). I rebooted again on the USB stick and did mount the new `/boot` on sda and [installed the Grub boot loader using this resource](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal). Rebooted again and this time everything was as expected.

I have selected Windows as the default boot (required by the IT department), and I do not need to enter twice my credentials (at boot prompt to unlock the disk, and then again to login to Windows, I only need to do it at boot prompt). But just after entering the boot prompt credentials (to unlock the disk) I can switch to Ubuntu if I would wish to.

So it has been working perfectly :-)